# In PHP the previous unique value to the next page save it to the database there, but I get an error. What can I do?

Tags: php, html, web, post, get

I want to transfer the previous unique value to the next page save it to the database there, but I get an error. What can I do? sayfaId is my problem.

***urunEkle.php***

```
 if ($_POST) { // Sayfada post olup olmadığını kontrol ediyoruz.
 $sayfaId=$_GET['sayfaId'];
 .......
 $satir = [
  'foto' => $dosya_adi,
  'baslik' => $baslik,
  'aktif' => $aktif,
  'sayfaId' =>$sayfaId,  
   ];

  $sql = "INSERT INTO sayfaurunleri SET foto=:foto, baslik=:baslik,aktif=:aktif,sayfaId=:sayfaId;";
                    $durum = $baglanti->prepare($sql)->execute($satir);
```

***sayfalar.php***

```
        <form action="" method="post">
        .......
        <td><a class="btn btn" href="urunEkle.php?sayfaId=<?= $sonuc["id"] ?>"><span class="fa fa- 
        edit fa-2x"></span></a></td>  </form>
```

**error**

```
  ( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: sayfaId in C:\wamp64\www\haktasmermer\admin\urunEkle.php on line 10
  Call Stack
  # Time    Memory  Function    Location
  1 0.0002  410592  {main}( )   ...\urunEkle.php:0
```

Comment: could you show the first 10 lines of urunEkle.php?  I think you’re looking in the wrong place

Comment: btw, clicking on the link doesn’t submit the form, nor does submitting the form pass `sayfaId`. If you want to send that as a get var, you need to put that in your `action`, you could try `<form action="?sayfaId=<?=$sonuc['id']?>">`. Otherwise, just pass it aa a post val from hidden input

Comment: Line 10 is  $sayfaId=$_GET['sayfaId'];

Comment: I hadn’t looked closely enough at your html. The form isn’t passing that variable. Is there a compelling reason for wanting it to be passed as a GET?

Comment: No, I dont understand why this so.when  I write  $sayfaId=$_GET['sayfaId']; out of if block, $sayfaId=$_GET['sayfaId']  run. But when I in if block this code dont run :/

Comment: in the same as sayfaId is primary key

Comment: Please edit your post to show the entirety of the form. I can’t be sure what exactly you’re posting. I already mentioned that the link is a problem, and asked why you are trying to pass this variable as a GET. Since you are changing data, POST is the appropriate method, but there’s no reason for `sayfaId` to be a GET.  I haven’t said anything about the actual query yet, but it has some serious issues when we get there.